# PHP insert mysql array from paypal response

Tags: php, database, insert, paypal

I'm trying to get transaction details of a `PayPal` account, which I was successfully in doing so, but I get this long (what i assume is an array) and I need to insert the details into a `MySQL` database. I've tried several `foreach` methods but apparently I am doing something wrong.

This is the reponse from `PayPal` after successful request (stored as `$httpParsedResponse`)

```
TransactionSearch Completed Successfully: Array (
    [L_TIMESTAMP0] => 2012%2d08%2d14T18%3a46%3a00Z 
    [L_TIMESTAMP1] => 2012%2d08%2d14T18%3a45%3a32Z 
    [L_TIMESTAMP2] => 2012%2d08%2d13T01%3a45%3a48Z 
    [L_TIMESTAMP3] => 2012%2d08%2d13T01%3a34%3a12Z 
    [L_TIMEZONE0] => GMT 
    [L_TIMEZONE1] => GMT 
    [L_TIMEZONE2] => GMT 
    [L_TIMEZONE3] => GMT 
    [L_TYPE0] => Payment 
    [L_TYPE1] => Payment 
    [L_TYPE2] => Payment 
    [L_TYPE3] => Transfer 
    [L_EMAIL0] => pmd_1333866_per%40yahoo%2ecom 
    [L_EMAIL1] => pmd_1333866_per%40yahoo%2ecom 
    [L_EMAIL2] => pmd_1333866_per%40yahoo%2ecom 
    [L_NAME0] => Joshua%20O 
    [L_NAME1] => Joshua%20O 
    [L_NAME2] => Joshua%20O 
    [L_NAME3] => PayPal 
    [L_TRANSACTIONID0] => 58289472YK615973G 
    [L_TRANSACTIONID1] => 4U113116FL1819900 
    [L_TRANSACTIONID2] => 2X978155KR373471P 
    [L_TRANSACTIONID3] => 3TH38971MF599302V 
    [L_STATUS0] => Completed 
    [L_STATUS1] => Completed 
    [L_STATUS2] => Completed 
    [L_STATUS3] => Completed 
    [L_AMT0] => %2d100%2e00 
    [L_AMT1] => %2d50%2e00 
    [L_AMT2] => %2d200%2e00 
    [L_AMT3] => 2000%2e00 
    [L_CURRENCYCODE0] => USD 
    [L_CURRENCYCODE1] => USD 
    [L_CURRENCYCODE2] => USD 
    [L_CURRENCYCODE3] => USD 
    [L_FEEAMT0] => 0%2e00 
    [L_FEEAMT1] => 0%2e00 
    [L_FEEAMT2] => 0%2e00 
    [L_FEEAMT3] => 0%2e00 
    [L_NETAMT0] => %2d100%2e00 
    [L_NETAMT1] => %2d50%2e00 
    [L_NETAMT2] => %2d200%2e00 
    [L_NETAMT3] => 2000%2e00 
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2012%2d08%2d25T17%3a59%3a01Z 
    [CORRELATIONID] => bf5b1a824d937 
    [ACK] => Success 
    [VERSION] => 51%2e0 
    [BUILD] => 3435050
)
```

Obviously enough I guess the array is structured as

```
 [L_TIMESTAMP0]
 [L_TIMESTAMP1]
 [L_TIMESTAMP2]
```

and this continues for how ever many sets of transaction details there are for each set, ie timestamp, timezone, type, email, ect...

In this case there are 3 sets of transaction details but whatever solution needs to be able to loop through it wheither there is only 1 transaction pulled or 100.

Like I said the only goal here is to take this returned array from PayPal and insert into a MySQL database.

I hope this makes sense, any help at all would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Im sorry I had to edit my old question because im a newbie I guess -  At any rate I think your code helped organize it a bit better, this is now the response I get... still confused on how to insert it into a mysql database tho...

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [timestamp] => 2012%2d08%2d14T18%3a46%3a00Z 
[timezone] => GMT 
[type] => Payment 
[email] => pmd_1333866_per%40yahoo%2ecom 
[name] => Joshua%20O 
[transactionid] => 58289472YK615973G 
[status] => Completed 
[amt] => %2d100%2e00 
[feeamt] => 0%2e00 
[netamt] => %2d100%2e00 )

[1] => Array ( [timestamp] => 2012%2d08%2d14T18%3a45%3a32Z 
[timezone] => GMT 
[type] => Payment 
[email] => pmd_1333866_per%40yahoo%2ecom 
[name] => Joshua%20O 
[transactionid] => 4U113116FL1819900
[status] => Completed
[amt] => %2d50%2e00 
[feeamt] => 0%2e00 
[netamt] => %2d50%2e00 ) 

[2] => Array ( [timestamp] => 2012%2d08%2d13T01%3a45%3a48Z 
[timezone] => GMT 
[type] => Payment 
[email] => pmd_1333866_per%40yahoo%2ecom 
[name] => Joshua%20O 
[transactionid] => 2X978155KR373471P 
[status] => Completed 
[amt] => %2d200%2e00 
[feeamt] => 0%2e00 
[netamt] => %2d200%2e00 ) 

[3] => Array ( [timestamp] => 2012%2d08%2d13T01%3a34%3a12Z 
[timezone] => GMT 
[type] => Transfer 
[email] => 
[name] => PayPal 
[transactionid] => 3TH38971MF599302V 
[status] => Completed 
[amt] => 2000%2e00 
[feeamt] => 0%2e00 
[netamt] => 2000%2e00 ) )
```

Comment: Maybe $httpParsedResponse is a string and not an array?
Try a var_dump of it

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas are:

`$numOfTransactions=intval((count($response)-5)/11);`

where 5 is the number of values not duplicated for each transaction and 11 is the number of values for each transaction. This depends on the structure being reliable.

OR

```
$numOfTransactions=0;
foreach ($response as $key=>$value){
 $check=strpos($key,'L_TIMESTAMP');
 if ($check===false) break;
 $numOfTransactions++;
}
```

Then you can loop through the response to structure your data

```
for ($i=0;$i<$numOfTransactions;$i++){
 $data[$i]=array("timestamp"=>$response['L_TIMESTAMP'.$i],"timezone"=>$response['L_TIMEZONE'.$i]...);
}
```